# Visulise numpy array using 3d- lego plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to visualize a numpy array using `lego' plot?

For instance:

the numpy array:

```
x = np.ones((3,3))
```

should be rendered as:

[image]

where each entry in the array is represented by a box.

Ideally this should work with 3d numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. This example is mostly copied from [astroML's page](http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/appendix/fig_broadcast_visual.html). This is not dynamic, but I hope it's enough to get you started.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor='w')
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], xticks=[], yticks=[], frameon=False)

def draw_cube(ax, xy, size, depth=0.4,
              edges=None, label=None,
              label_kwargs=None, **kwargs):

    if edges is None:
        edges = range(1, 13)

    x, y = xy

    if 1 in edges:
        ax.plot([x, x + size],
                [y + size, y + size], **kwargs)
    if 2 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + size, x + size],
                [y, y + size], **kwargs)
    if 3 in edges:
        ax.plot([x, x + size],
                [y, y], **kwargs)
    if 4 in edges:
        ax.plot([x, x],
                [y, y + size], **kwargs)

    if 5 in edges:
        ax.plot([x, x + depth],
                [y + size, y + depth + size], **kwargs)
    if 6 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + size, x + size + depth],
                [y + size, y + depth + size], **kwargs)
    if 7 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + size, x + size + depth],
                [y, y + depth], **kwargs)
    if 8 in edges:
        ax.plot([x, x + depth],
                [y, y + depth], **kwargs)

    if 9 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + depth, x + depth + size],
                [y + depth + size, y + depth + size], **kwargs)
    if 10 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + depth + size, x + depth + size],
                [y + depth, y + depth + size], **kwargs)
    if 11 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + depth, x + depth + size],
                [y + depth, y + depth], **kwargs)
    if 12 in edges:
        ax.plot([x + depth, x + depth],
                [y + depth, y + depth + size], **kwargs)

    if label:
        if label_kwargs is None:
            label_kwargs = {}
        ax.text(x + 0.5 * size, y + 0.5 * size, label,
                ha='center', va='center', **label_kwargs)

solid = dict(c='black', ls='-', lw=1,
             label_kwargs=dict(color='k'))

depth=0.4

draw_cube(ax, (1, 2), 1, depth, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (2, 2), 1, depth, [1, 2, 3, 6, 9], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (3, 2), 1, depth, [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10], '1', **solid)

draw_cube(ax, (1, 1), 1, depth, [2, 3, 4], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (2, 1), 1, depth, [2, 3], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (3, 1), 1, depth, [2, 3, 7, 10], '1', **solid)

draw_cube(ax, (1, 0), 1, depth, [2, 3, 4], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (2, 0), 1, depth, [2, 3], '1', **solid)
draw_cube(ax, (3, 0), 1, depth, [2, 3, 7, 10], '1', **solid)

ax.set_xlim(0, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 4)
plt.show()
```

[image: 1]